# Mark elements in powerpoint to use it in program

Tags: c#, xml, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I am looking for some kind of mark for elements in PowerPoint presentation. In word I have RichTextControl it has tag/title and its easy to implement, and find out by code. The problem is because PowerPoint doesn't have this kind of control. I can receive by code only elements from slides by iterate them. and only thing I have is relations ship ID. It there any way to use RichTextControl in powerpoint/excel? or import them? I was trying to use other control but there is no like this

Answer (score 1):

The Presentation object, each slide object and each shape can have any number of tags.

For example:

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  .Tags.Add "MyShapeID", "Some string value"
End With
```

To retrieve the shape later, iterate through the shapes collection:

```
For Each oSh in oSl.Shapes
   If oSh.Tags("MyShapeID") = "Some string value" Then
      MsgBox "We found it!"
   End If
Next
```